# Best action to take when importing existing data into lportal

Tags: java, liferay

I'm a liferay beginner and I've been at it for weeks now, but still I'm finding liferay a little hard to use...... especially because of the constraints I'm faced with,, If it's possible can you lend me some of your opinion on my situation?,,,,, to make the story short here it is

I need to make forms using dynamic data list(DDL) first....
After I made the whole site, I'd need to import data into it.. of course those data would have to be viewed using the pre-made DDLs.... this is my problem...
I mean it's really easy to make forms using DDL,,, but after that I need to still make the migrated information viewable and editable in those DDL's

What do you think the right steps should be,, please enlighten me... :(
oh aside from that, I made the DDLs in WCM,,,, how do I approach this problem of mine,, please help

PS the migration I did in eclipse using service builder,,, but the DDLs on the WCM.....

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by migrating DDLs or importing DDLs? Do you have two portals and you are creating DDLs in one and want to migrate the same to another portal? Also can you list down the steps as to how you created the DDLs through WCM? it would also be great to have some relevant screen-shot of the portlets. What version of Liferay are you using? Thanks

Comment: All of my tools are 6.2 CE ga4, I have only one portal, what I'm trying to do is to migrate/import contents from a database using service builder, however I am required to use dynamic data lists instead of hardcoding my forms.... the steps I did is as follows (1) created the DDL (2) created a portlet where I wrote code to transfer the data from other database to DDMContent(because DDLcontents go here right) (3) now the problem is how I would display my data in the dynamic datalist I created earlier.... I just want to know if it's possible,, and if it is how can I do it? Thanks,, please answer

Comment: boss wants to make use of the automatic CRUD function of dynamic datalist..... that is why he wants to import existing database into DDMContent....

Comment: suggestions are welcome,, if there IS another way I'm very interested....

Comment: existing database? That means you have two databases - lportal and one other which already has some custom data? And you have written custom portlet to import the data in DDL? And that portlet is inserting the data properly? So now what is issue, can't you use the DDL display portlet?

Comment: it doesn't display in my pre made DDL... I don't know why,, but it IS in the database > DDMContent table ,,,,, the xml formatting I used is different from the way liferay formats records...

Comment: Did you try changing the xml formatting? can you post a sample of your DDM content?

Comment: I just decided yesterday to not use DDMContent as storage of imported data,,, I talked to boss and we agreed that I hardcode the CRUDs  into portlets,,, It will also be easier for me to create my own tables using service,,, instead of using Liferay's default tables.. but I'll try to get back at this problem later...